# How to change color of a badge programmatically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i would like to know how can i change the color of a badge programmtically in angular.
i would like to be able to set the color of the badge initially to white and if the `percVLRiskTotal` is equal a specific value, then the color of the badge should be set to green for an example.

**css**:

```
<span class="badge badge-purple">{{percVLRiskTotal}} <span class="clr-sr-only"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set a style class conditionally in Angular. For your case, you could do something like:

```
<span class="badge" [class.badge-green]="percVLRiskTotal === 1000">
    {{percVLRiskTotal}} <span class="clr-sr-only">
</span>
```

This will apply the class named `badge-green` to the `span` element if the value of the `percVLRiskTotal` property equals 1,000.

More information can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding).

Comment: thanks for the answer.is it possible to set width and height to the badge?i want to expand it alitte bit to assimilate the entire value specially it contains 4 digits after the floating point, is that possible

Comment: The linked page in my answer contains information on how to apply conditional styles. This can easily be used to set width and height.

Comment: I feel I am a bit lost. I will add in Id to <span> then,in the css file, I will set width and height…is that a recommended approach to do it..please advice

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample I think u can use ngClass like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'badge-purple': yourCondition === 'Option'}"
```

or for multiple conditions:

```
[ngClass]="{'badge-purple': yourCondition1 === 'Option1', 'badge-red' : yourCondition2 === 'Option2' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to achieve. This
here I think you can use the ngStyle directive provided by angular

```
<span class="badge" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': percVLRiskTotal == 50 ? 'green':'blue'}">{{percVLRiskTotal}} <span class="clr-sr-only"></span>
```